# Divide ndarray by maximums along given axis

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, tensor

Say I have an array like this

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2]*9 + [3]*9 + [4]*9])
a = a.reshape((-1,3, 3))
print(a)
```

Which is

```
[[[2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[3 3 3]
  [3 3 3]
  [3 3 3]]

 [[4 4 4]
  [4 4 4]
  [4 4 4]]]
```

So for example, if I want to divide every object in axis 0 by its max value (to get 1's only), how would I do that without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the maximum value in each `ndarray` in the first axis by taking the [`np.max`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) along their rows and columns, setting `keepdims=True` so `a` is divided by the resulting maximum values along the first axis:

```
a / np.max(a, axis=(1,2), keepdims=True)
```

**Output**

```
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

Comment: He wants to divide every element in axis 0 by its max value.  If you change a single value in any of the sub arrays this answer is incorrect.  You are doing row wise maximum within each element.

Comment: You're right @user3483203 thx for pointing out, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above answer I thought it would be useful to extend this to transformations requiring more than just a single numpy function, e.g. normalization in [0,1] using min/max:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

def zero_one_normalize_3d(arr):
    fs = np.min, np.max
    arr_min, arr_max = [f(arr, axis = (1, 2), keepdims = True) for f in fs]
    return (arr - arr_min) / (arr_max - arr_min)

def zero_one_normalize_2d(arr):
    return (arr - arr.min()) / (arr.max() - arr.min())

points = 10000
x1 = np.random.normal(3, 10, points)
x2 = np.random.normal(6, 10, points)
x3 = np.random.normal(9, 10, points)
a = np.column_stack((x1, x2, x3))
a = a.reshape(-1, 10, 3)

print(np.alltrue(zero_one_normalize_3d(a)[0] == zero_one_normalize_2d(a[0])))
> True
```